# Top align an image after hover

Tags: html, css

I hope you are doing well on this holiday (in France anyway).

I have a small problem that requires your expertise, I want the image I display on the flyover to be always positioned at 3.88889rem from the top of my page, whatever the link I fly over.  To make it more explicit I put the link of my JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yohkouma/ynbd8361/2/#&togetherjs=SqNlcfPa8q

```css
.container-case {
  padding-right: 0rem !important;
  display: inline-block;
}

.case {
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*margin-right: 1rem;*/
  z-index: 1;
  height: 6rem;
}

.case span {
  /*position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;*/
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Circular Std';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: z-index 0.1s, color 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.case .snippet {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 33.5rem;
  /*top: 1rem;*/
  vertical-align: top;
}

/*.case:hover {
  z-index: 4;
}*/
.case:hover .snippet {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.4s;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 33.5rem;
  /*top: 1rem;*/
  margin-left: 2rem
}

.case:hover span {
  z-index: 5;
  color: transparent !important;
  transition: z-index 0.1s, color 0.4s;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1F1969;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.0625rem;
}

/*BPCE*/
#bpce {
  width: 100%;
}

#bpce span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#bpce .snippet {}

/*La mutuelle Générale*/
#lmg {
  width: 100%;
}

#lmg span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#lmg .snippet {}

/*Malakoff Médéric Humanis*/
#mmh {
  width: 100%;
}

#mmh span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#mmh .snippet {}

/*Centre Pompidou Mobile*/
#cpm {
  width: 100%;
}

#cpm span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#cpm .snippet {}

/*Esphi*/

#connect {
  width: 100%;
}

#connect span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#connect .snippet {}
```

```html
<div class="work">

  <div class="container-case">

    <div class="case" id="bpce">

      <a href="http://yohkouma.com/project/bpce"><span>bpce</span></a>

      <img class="snippet" src="http://yohkouma.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/bpce_thumbnail_purple-1.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="picture 1">

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container-case">

    <div class="case" id="mmh">

      <a href="#"><span>malakoff méderic humanis</span></a>

      <img class="snippet" src="http://yohkouma.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Amm2.jpg" width="auto" height="auto" alt="picture 1">

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container-case">

    <div class="case" id="cpm">

      <a href="http://yohkouma.com/project/centre-pompidou-mobile"><span>jeffrey</span></a>

      <img class="snippet" src="http://yohkouma.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/cpm_poster_thumbnail.jpg" width="auto" height="auto" alt="picture 1">

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container-case">

    <div class="case" id="lmg">

      <a href="http://yohkouma.com/project/la-mutuelle-generale"><span>la mutuelle générale</span></a>

      <img class="snippet" src="http://yohkouma.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/la_mutuelle_générale.jpg" width="auto" height="auto" alt="picture 1">

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="container-case">

    <div class="case" id="connect">

      <a href="http://yohkouma.com/project/connect"><span>connect+</span></a>

      <img class="snippet" src="http://yohkouma.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/thumbnail_connect.jpg" width="auto" height="auto" alt="picture 1">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't found JSfiddle link. Please add it. So contributors can help you.

Comment: Hello, i've put the JSfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
.container-case {
  padding-right: 0rem !important;
  display: block;
}

.case {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 6rem;
}

.case span {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Circular Std';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: z-index 0.1s, color 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.case .snippet {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 33.5rem;
  vertical-align: top;
}


.case:hover .snippet {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 0.4s;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  top:  3.88889rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.case:hover span {
  z-index: 5;
  color: transparent !important;
  transition: z-index 0.1s, color 0.4s;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #1F1969;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.0625rem;
}

/*BPCE*/
#bpce {
  width: 100%;
}

#bpce span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#bpce .snippet {}

/*La mutuelle Générale*/
#lmg {
  width: 100%;
}

#lmg span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#lmg .snippet {}

/*Malakoff Médéric Humanis*/
#mmh {
  width: 100%;
}

#mmh span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#mmh .snippet {}

/*Centre Pompidou Mobile*/
#cpm {
  width: 100%;
}

#cpm span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#cpm .snippet {}

/*Esphi*/

#connect {
  width: 100%;
}

#connect span {
  color: #1F1969;
}

#connect .snippet {}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/go7pubcn/2/)

Comment: Yes it's Thank you very much man, i was scratching my head so hard ! 

Comment: no problem. Consider marking it as an answer, so other people can find it usefull too

Comment: No problem, i'm doing this